# Regex beginner confusion

Tags: c#, regex

**Input :**

Hello my name is **X**. Blah Blah Blah

**EDIT 1:** Any user can enter his name substituted with X. So **X** is a variable with variable lenght.

**Required Output :**

Hello my name is Ahmed
*Where X = Ahmed*

**Pattern :**

```
(Hello my name is .+)\.
```

Really, this's a newbie question :(  ,, I just start learning.
**Not Working !**

Comment: So are you trying to get all input up to and including `X` if `X = Ahmed`?

Comment: this is a helpful website for RegEx testing: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: @kaveman Some are worked in sites ans not working in my code testing. This is because of I include `@` at the beginning of the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really have no clue what your pattern is attempting to accomplish, so I will start at the beginning. What you want to do is to match `Hello my name is X`.  We can do that like so.

```
/Hello my name is X\./
```

But we don't want to capture the *letter* X, we want to match what would be in X's place.  So now our regex becomes.

```
/Hello my name is .+\./
```

So the former regex now matches any character one or more times.  Now we want to capture that and use it outside of the regex.  We can do this with the capture, `()`, operator.

```
/Hello my name is (.+)\./
```

Now the question is, "How do we get the capture?"  Well `Regex.Match` returns a `Match`.  Now `Match` has a property called `Groups` which is a collection of all the captures from the regex.  So our final, code is.

```
var match = Regex.Match("Hello my name is dunsmoreb.", @"Hello my name is (.+)\.");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]); // Prints `dunsmoreb`.
```

Comment: Sorry, What's the `/` operation ?

Comment: That just marks the beginning and end of a regex.  This is not required in .NET.

Comment: I tested it. It gives me errors because of \. So I included `@` at the beginning of the pattern string, then it doesn't work !

Comment: Unrecognized Escape Sequence !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10819/discussion-between-ahmed-ghoneim-and-dunsmoreb)

Comment: Sorry about that, you need to prefix the pattern with `@` so the `\.` doesn't get interpreted as an escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

When you see a regex with a backslash in it, that will need to be interpreted as a literal backslash by the regex engine.  This means that if your programming language uses `\` for escaping in strings, for every `\` in a regex you will need `\\` in your string.

For example, to use the regex `Hello my name is (.+)\.`, you may need to use the following string:

```
"Hello my name is (.+)\\."
```

Note that this may not be the exact regex you want, for example with a string like "Hello my name is Ahmed. Blah blah." you would get "Ahmed. Blah blah" as the name because `(.+)` is greedy.  You could change the `(.+)` to `(.+?)` to fix this, but if `.` was a valid character in a name (for example "J.R.R. Tolkien") you would run into a similar problem where you don't match enough.

Comment: You can also prefix your string with `@`.

Answer (score 0):

use the following:

```
Hello my name is (\w+)
```

`(\w+)` matches characters that form a word. If you have spaces in the name say 'John Doe' this will match only 'John'

Look here for more explanation on regex usage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but I must include his name totally.